# Replace string characters with a single comma

Tags: ruby, string

I want to remove unwanted symbols from this string:

```
myString = String.new("@@106#107#Hello@@106#World@@")
```

and separate each word with a comma. The desired result is:

```
"Hello, World"
```

Any ideas on how to achieve my desired result? What I tried is this:

```
myString.gsub!(/[@#0123456789]/, ',')
print myString + "\n"
# => ",,,,,,,,,,Hello,,,,,,World,,"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways:

```
myString.scan(/[a-zA-Z]+/).join(', ')
=> "Hello, World"
```

Comment: Elegant!! So *+1*... :)

Comment: (To be exactly like the regular expression in the question, you could use `[^@#0-9]`.)

Comment: I gave a +1 please do the same to my question as someone as down voted for no reason

Answer (score 3):

```
myString.gsub(/(\A)?[^a-zA-Z]+(\z)?/){$1 || $2 ? "" : ", "}
# => "Hello, World"
```